# Iphone Simulator - Allocates way too much memory and runs slow compared to device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory, simulator

I've seen plenty of posts about the simulator running slow, but my problem is different.

I ran my app with instruments and saw that in the device, the app uses about 8mb of live memory when the app is running. In the simulator the live memory is about 50MB, and I have no idea why this is.

This causes the simulator to lag and I need it to run smooth so i can take a nice screen capture video of my app.

Any ideas?

Comment: Define slow. May be some simulator specific code using `#define`s? There's also a switch to make animations run slowly.

Comment: What exactly is it your app is doing? You'll probably need to provide more information to get a useful answer.

Comment: It's a 2D game using openGL. there ARE quite a few animations...

Comment: By slow, I mean low frame rate. everything is laggy and jumpy.

Comment: Note that the simulator is just that, a simulator. Things will be different, as it's running on a totally different architecture than the actual device.

Comment: Isn't there a HDMI port to Apple device cable of some sort? Or for projectors or Apple TV? Then record the video off your output screen or similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of steps in the OpenGL ES 1.1/2.0 pipeline that are done in software when running on the simulator (as the Mac GPUs are plain OpenGL) but are hardware accelerated when running on the device (hence it actually running faster on the device).

From the documentation:

> Important: Rendering performance of OpenGL ES in Simulator has no
>   relation to the performance of OpenGL ES on an actual device.
>   Simulator provides an optimized software rasterizer that takes
>   advantage of the vector processing capabilities of your Macintosh
>   computer. As a result, your OpenGL ES code may run faster or slower in
>   iOS simulator (depending on your computer and what you are drawing)
>   than on an actual device. Always profile and optimize your drawing
>   code on a real device and never assume that Simulator reflects
>   real-world performance.

This definitely explains the speed discrepancy, might also explain the extra memory taken up when running in the simulator.

Comment: That seems likely. Because my game uses a lot of particle emitters that are openGL es heavy, maybe that's why. Thanks!