# App memory usage difference between simulator and device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, memory, simulator

I ran my app on my Macbook Air and my Iphone 6s and the below image is the memory usage profile after I go through all the UI in my apps. In the two scenario, I have performed similar tasks and duration. Why is the simulator memory usage so much higher than the actual device. Should I be concerned even though the device memory usage seems to be reasonable?

[image]

Comment: Upvote for your good question

Comment: Edward Hung check my answer brother

Comment: Now I updated check my answer with source.

Comment: Is my answer helpful or do you need more?

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks again champ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good Question.I appreciate you for asking this kind of question.

[Apple Documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html)

> Simulator is a useful tool, but it should not be the only way you test an app. Because the simulator is an app running on a Mac, it has access to the computer’s resources, including the CPU, memory, and network connection. All of these resources are likely to be faster than those found on a mobile device. As a result, the simulator is not an accurate test of an app’s performance, memory usage, and networking speed. For this same reason, always test the performance of your app’s user interface on a device. In Simulator, your app’s user interface may appear to run both faster and smoother than on a device

[Xcode’s iOS simulator reports 2GB RAM for iPhone 6S, 4GB for iPad Pro](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/09/xcodes-ios-simulator-reports-2gb-ram-for-iphone-6s-4gb-for-ipad-pro/)

[Xcode's iOS simulator shows 2GB of RAM for iPhone 6s and 6s Plus, 4GB for iPad Pro](http://www.imore.com/xcodes-ios-simulator-shows-2gb-ram-iphone-6s-and-6s-plus-4gb-ipad-pro)

Finally the solution from discussion is

[Why the iPhone Simulator is Awesome](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1249438)

I found the exact solution from jbat100's answer.

> Rendering performance of OpenGL ES in Simulator has no relation to the performance of OpenGL ES on an actual device. Simulator provides an optimized software rasterizer that takes advantage of the vector processing capabilities of your Macintosh computer. As a result, your OpenGL ES code may run faster or slower in iOS simulator (depending on your computer and what you are drawing) than on an actual device. Always profile and optimize your drawing code on a real device and never assume that Simulator reflects real-world performance.

[Iphone Simulator - Allocates way too much memory and runs slow compared to device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705374/iphone-simulator-allocates-way-too-much-memory-and-runs-slow-compared-to-devic)

Comment: I saw this somewhere before. However, my macbook air is 2015 with 4GB ram. I would expected the simulator (which has the processing power of my mac) to perform the same or better than my actual 6s. Moreover, the mac simulator uses nearly 0.5GB of memory as oppose to the 70mb on my phone. Does that mean I can simply ignore the result from my mac even if it is 7x more?

Comment: The site cant be reached, could you please update it

Comment: Yes Now I can't reach this.I will check.

Comment: No wonder http://allocates%20way%20too%20much%20memory%20and%20runs%20slow%20compared%20to%20device/ can't be reached. Please correct the URL

Comment: Thank you for remaining that NSNoob.